# Access parent field values from custom field definition

Tags: 2010, development, content-type, custom-field-types, validation

I've got a form that contains different custom fields. During vallidation of field1 I need to know the value of field2.

Does anyone know how to access the field? Or perhabs it is possible to connect the custom conntenttype (which contains the custom fields) to a c# class (which contains a validation logic)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Form as in InfoPath form? or just the default Add/Edit forms of SharePoint?

Comment: I'm using the default Add/Edit-Forms.